How to fix Windsurf refusing to log in?
If I download Windsurf and try to launch it, then it asks me to log in. This opens my browser in which I log in successfully to their website. But this is supposed to cause the app to log in too, and yet it loads forever with Browser redirect not working:

If I instead click on "Try manual auth", then after pasting the token it fails too with Invalid auth token:

If I then click open debug logs nothing happens.
If Windsurf is launched via the command prompt, it outputs just a few lines plus "cannot find the file" for the missing debug log:

Tried multiple browsers and also reinstalling and deleting c:\users\[my user]\.codeium\windsurf
Is there a way to make it work or at least monitor why it fails?

I've ended up deleting my account from their website, created another account and this time it worked.
